# Deploy an Android based project in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I built an app in Android using webview and Phonegap. I used the code below to add a Javascript interface so that I can call methods on Helper.java from Javascript. While this works when I deploy the app using Android, it doesn't work when I am using PhoneGap.

I am uploading the .zip file of the Android project to PhoneGap and then generating .apk file through the Phonegap build. However as I said this app does not connect to the Helper class for some reason. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks.

```
public class FinderApp extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(new Helper(), "helper");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more information about your problem: Phonegap Build does not expect anything other than html (+js+css+resources..) and a config.xml file. It will not do anything with your .java file (this service builds for all output OSes at once).

If you want to your special code to be used by the phonegap build, you would need to make it into a plugin (see links in other answer), but then you will also need to wait because right now the Build service does only handle the ChildBrowser plugin, not custom plugins:

> Right now, you cannot submit your own plugins to PhoneGap Build and have them included on our system. We are working on the infrastructure changes to allow this support.

See [this page](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins) for more information.

I'm afraid if you want to compile your code, you'll need to do without Phonegap Build for the moment and [compile it yourself](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Turn your Helper.Java into a [Phonegap plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS).

Comment: The actual link he's looking for would rather be [How to create a Phonegap plugin for Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)